# Designing / combining redux reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am cleaning up my reducer setup which was wrong from the beginning. I using the [redux doco](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) and [the ducks pattern](https://github.com/erikras/ducks-modular-redux) to set it right.

I want to separate/divide my state like the [doco suggests](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BasicReducerStructure.html):

```
{
    domainData1 : {},
    domainData2 : {},
    appState1 : {},
    appState2 : {},
    ui : {
        uiState1 : {},
        uiState2 : {},
    }
}
```

In my case I have some albums, catalogs and photos which I'm trying to manage. The state should look something like this:

```
{
    //domainData
    albums : {...},
    catalogs : {...},
    photos : {...},

    //appState
    selectedAlbum : {...},

    //uiState
    ui : {
        loading : {},
        uiState2 : {},
    }
}
```

I have put all code belonging to albums in one file where actions, action creators, recuders and API is located
similar for catalogs and photos.
Then I combine the reducers with combineReducers in a separate file.

Code below...

My question is... when I do stuff on albums I will want all the domain data to go into the albums branch of the state. But I don't want the ui and app state stuff to go into the albums branch - this should go in to the app and ui state branches. that's not possible with my setup, e.g. when loading albums I set the loading flag in the "albums" reducer, this is the fed til the combineReducer, and the result is that the loading state becomes part of the albums branch of the state...

Albums module:

```
import { createRequest, responseHandler, notAuthorized } from './apiUtils';
import { List, Map, fromJS } from 'immutable';

//actions
const REQUEST_ALBUMS = 'REQUEST_ALBUMS';
const FETCH_ALBUMS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_ALBUMS_SUCCESS';
const FETCH_ALBUM_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_ALBUM_SUCCESS';
const REQUEST_ALBUM = 'REQUEST_ALBUM';
const CREATE_ALBUM = 'CREATE_ALBUM';
const CREATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS = 'CREATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS';
const UPDATE_ALBUM = 'UPDATE_ALBUM';
const UPDATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS = 'UPDATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS';

// Reducer
var init = Map(fromJS({
  albums: [],
  album: [],
  loading: false,
}));

var newState = null;

export function reducer(state=init, action={}) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case FETCH_ALBUMS_SUCCESS: {
      newState = state
        .set('albums', fromJS(action.payload.albums))
        .set('loading', false);
      return newState;
    }

    case REQUEST_ALBUMS: {
      return state.set('loading', true);
    }

    case FETCH_ALBUM_SUCCESS: {
      newState = state
        .set('album', fromJS(action.payload.album))
        .set('loading', false);
      return newState;
    }

    case REQUEST_ALBUM: {
      return state.set('loading', true);
    }

    case CREATE_ALBUM: {
      return state.set('loading', true);
    }

    case CREATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS: {
      newState = state
        .set('album', fromJS(action.payload.album))
        .set('loading', false);
      return newState;
    }

    case UPDATE_ALBUM: {
      return state.set('loading', true);
    }

    case UPDATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS: {
      newState = state
        .set('album', fromJS(action.payload.album))
        .set('loading', false);
      return newState;
    }
  }
  return state;
}

// Action Creators
export function getAlbumsPending(response) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_ALBUMS,
  };
}

export function getAlbumsSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_ALBUMS_SUCCESS,
    payload: response,
  };
}

export function getAlbumPending(response) {
  return {
    type: REQUEST_ALBUM,
  };
}

export function getAlbumSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: FETCH_ALBUM_SUCCESS,
    payload: response,
  };
}

function createAlbumPending(response) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_ALBUM,
  };
}

function createAlbumSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS,
    payload: response,
  };
}

export function updateAlbumPending(response) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ALBUM,
  };
}

export function updateAlbumSuccess(response) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS,
    payload: response,
  };
}

//API

export function fetchAlbums() {
  //API url
  const url = '/api/albums.json';

  //make the call
  return dispatch => {

    dispatch(getAlbumsPending());

    fetch(createRequest('GET', url, null))
    .then(response => responseHandler(response))
    .then(data => dispatch(getAlbumsSuccess(data)))
    .catch(error => console.log('request failed', error));
  };
}

export function fetchAlbum(id) {
  //url
  var url = '/api/albums/'.concat(id);

  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(getAlbumPending());

    fetch(createRequest('GET', url, null))
    .then(response => responseHandler(response))
    .then(data => dispatch(getAlbumSuccess({ album: data })))
    .catch(error => console.log('request failed', error));
  };
}

export function createAlbum(params) {
  //API url
  const url = '/api/albums/';

  return dispatch => {

    dispatch(createAlbumPending());

    fetch(createRequest('POST', url, params))
    .then(response => responseHandler(response))
    .then(data => dispatch(createAlbumSuccess({ album: data })))
    .catch(error => console.log('request failed', error));
  };
}

export function updateAlbum(params) {
  //API url
  var url = '/api/albums/'.concat(params.id);

  //make the call
  return dispatch => {

    dispatch(updateAlbumPending());

    fetch(createRequest('PUT', url, params))
    .then(response => responseHandler(response))
    .then(data => dispatch(updateAlbumSuccess({ album: data })))
    .catch(error => console.log('request failed', error));
  };
}
```

CombineRecucer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as albumReducer } from '../actions/album';
import { reducer as catalogReducer } from '../actions/catalog';

export default combineReducers({
  albums: albumReducer,  // <- loading flag ends up here
  catalogs: catalogReducer,
  loading: // I want loading flag here 
});
```

Sorry for the long post - no potato

Comment: you must add the `case UPDATE_ALBUM:` stuff in the `loading` reducer. You can import the action types from the other duck file. The albums reducer is only responsible for updating its own slice of the state. Multiple reducers can listen to the same action types, and do some changes to their own slice.

Comment: OMG...so simple.. I totally missed the genius of redux...@HåkenLid put up an answer so I can credit you

Comment: Sure. I've added an answer.

Comment: Utterly unconnected with your actual question: I don't know what you think you are doing with the `newState` variable, but you're not.  In general, when you are writing functional code (including Redux code), try always to use `const` instead of `var` -- many things become clearer.

Comment: thanks for the good advice @Malvolio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just move that logic to the Loading reducer responsible for that slice of the state.

```
// ducks/Loading.js

import {
  REQUEST_ALBUM,
  CREATE_ALBUM,
  CREATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS
} from 'ducks/Albums'  
// remember to also export from the Albums duck.

export const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_ALBUM:
    case CREATE_ALBUM:
      return state.set('loading', true)

    case CREATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS:
      return state.set('loading', false)
  }
}
```

You can import the action types from the other duck file. 
The `Albums` reducer is only responsible for updating its own slice of the state.

Multiple reducers can listen to the same action types, and do some changes to their own slice. So `CREATE_ALBUM_SUCCESS` can also trigger some change in the Albums reducer.

You can also implement this in some other way. For instance by using a key in the `meta` field of an action. This avoids having to do lots of imports and exports, since the reducer doesn't have to know the type of the action.

```
// loading reducer
export const reducer = (state = false, action) => 
  (action.meta && action.meta.loading !== undefined)
    ? action.meta.loading
    : state


// action creator
export const updateAlbumPending = () => ({
  type: UPDATE_ALBUM,
  meta: {
    loading: true
  }
})
```